# How to RETRIEVE a cookie in coldfusion?

Tags: html, cookies, coldfusion

**The Situation:**
I know how to set a cookie like this:
`<cfcookie name="firstName" expires="never" value="#url.firstName#">`

**The Question:**
Using coldfusion, **how can I RETRIEVE the value of this cookie** later? Saw many resources online about setting but nothing useful about retrieving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the cookie scope like this:

```
<cfoutput>#cookie.firstName#</cfoutput>
```

More information on scopes is at http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Variables_30.html